# Ajax not working from the initial load of the grid, Templates and ClientTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

I have the following code:

```
@using com.mycompany.myproject.web.ViewModels
@model IEnumerable

@{ Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Deducciones")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.IdDeducciones).ClientTemplate("");
        columns.Bound(p => p.FechaInscripcion).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FechaFin).Width(400);
                        })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        //Ajax binding
        .Ajax()
        //The action method which will return JSON
        .Select("DeduccionesAjax", "Empleados", new { id = ViewBag.Id })
    )
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(2))
    .Sortable()
    .Render(); }
```

The grid renders fine but only uses the client template when I go to page 2 for instance. On the initial load it doesn't use it.
As a workaround I added `.Template(@<text><a href='#'>@item.IdDeducciones</a></text>);` after the ClientTemplate and now it works on both the initial load and afterwards. However this seems strange as none of the examples or docs I've seen specify both a Template and a ClientTemplate.

Is there something I'm missing that's making the first load not come from Ajax or something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I replied in the [forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/clienttemplate-and-template-at-the-same-time.aspx) which you opened in the Telerik forums this is expected and [documented](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-troubleshooting.html#ClientTemplatesDoNotApplyInitially). Client templates apply only when doing client binding (such as ajax). Templates are applied during server binding such as :

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
```

Comment: The troubleshooting link solved the issue. I must say, however that such information belongs to the Ajax Binding chapter.